# is there a tool in Eclipse like command line?

Tags: eclipse, maven

so that you can type os commands right in Eclipse?

calls to mvn for example..

Answer (score 4):

The most common way is probably to use Wicked Shell: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wicked-shell

> Wicked Shell - A non-evil eclipse plugin providing an integrated shell. This plugin enables the use of the system shell directly from the eclipse IDE.

A screen-shot:

[image]

You should also consider *Run* -> *External Tools*.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has this feature built-in. Go to **Window > Show View > Other...** then select **Remote Systems**. Unfold the tree, **right-click** on **Local Shells** and select **Lauch Shell**.

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/9981/screenshot002a.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/9981/screenshot002a.png)

Comment: Yes, it works (and then some), but you need the TM/RSE installed for that. 
http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/

Comment: @zvikico Thanks for the clarification. Actually, TM/RSE is part of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, which I use, so I didn't thought about this. But it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [easyshell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell) as well. It's not exactly what you want, but many people find it very helpful.

Comment: Easy shell will open external terminal